# In reactjs convert-csv-to-json return error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

While using https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-csv-to-json in reactjs.I am getting error `Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import $ from 'jquery';
export default class CsvRead extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  CsvRead() {
    let csvToJson = require('convert-csv-to-json');
    let json = csvToJson.getJsonFromCsv("../../MonthlySummaryDetailsCSV.csv");
    for(let i=0; i<json.length;i++){
    console.log(json[i]);
    }

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div >{this.CsvRead()}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

convert-csv-to-json is meant to work with `fs` which stands for `filesystem`. That means it will only work in Node environments, not browser environments.

If you need to convert CSV to JSON/JS in the browser, you could see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979002/convert-csv-data-into-json-format-using-javascript) for a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import * as XLSX from 'xlsx'

const SheetJSFT = [
    "xlsx",
    "xlsb",
    "xlsm",
    "xls",
    "xml",
    "csv",
    "txt",
    "ods",
    "fods",
    "uos",
    "sylk",
    "dif",
    "dbf",
    "prn",
    "qpw",
    "123",
    "wb*",
    "wq*",
    "html",
    "htm"
].map(x=>`.${x}`).join(",");

export const useCsvUpload = () => {
    const handleFileReader = (file, callback) => {
        /* Boilerplate to set up FileReader */
        const reader = new FileReader();
        const rABS = !!reader.readAsBinaryString;
        reader.onload = (e) => {
            /* Parse data */
            const bstr = e.target.result;
            const wb = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: rABS ? 'binary' : 'array', bookVBA: true });
            /* Get first worksheet */
            const workSheetName = wb.SheetNames[0];
            const workSheet = wb.Sheets[workSheetName];
            /* Convert array of arrays */
            const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet).map(item => ({
                ...item,
                key: item.__rowNum__,
            }))
            /* Update state */
            callback(jsonData)
        };

        if (rABS) {
            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        } else {
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        };
    }

    return {
        handleFileReader,
        sheetAccepted: SheetJSFT
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).