# What is the best way to convert from CSV to JSON when commas and quotations may be in the fields?

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to convert a CSV to JSON. The csv comes in as free text like this (with the newlines):

```
name,age,booktitle
John,2,Hello World
Mary,3,""Alas, What Can I do?""
Joseph,5,"Waiting, waiting, waiting"
```

My problem as you can tell is the file...

- Has got some interior commas in some fields, though they are wrapped in at least one double quote.
- There could be double quotes within the file.

I would like the output to not have any leading and trailing quotes for each field... how can I correctly create a JSON object parsed out from the csv string that represents this CSV accurately? (without the leading and trailing quotes).

I usually use:

```
var mycsvstring;
var finalconvertedjson = {};
var headerfields = // get headers here
var lines = mycsvstring.split('\n');


for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
// loop through each line and set a key for each header field that corresponds to the appropriate lines[i]    
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Perhaps this page might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979002/convert-csv-data-into-json-format-using-javascript

Comment: CSV to JSON: convert the CSV into JavaScript Objects, then `JSON.stringify` (do you really want JSON, a string representation of data, or you just want an array of data?) P.S. there is no such thing as a "JSON object"

Comment: @Thefourthbird I can't rely on having a delimiter that is not a comma, any symbol is fair game.. would like to get this working with commas.

Comment: You can add your own logic of reading character by character. Keep looking for a qoute and a comma, if you find a comma first then take the value till next comma, and if you find a quote take value till next quote with condition that next char should be comma or end line.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My first guess is to use a regular expression. You can try this one I've just whipped up ([regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/xG5maE/5)):

```
/\s*(")?(.*?)\1\s*(?:,|$)/gm
```

This can be used to extract fields, so headers can be grabbed with it as well. The first capture group is used as an optional quote-grabber with a backreference (`\1`), so the actual data is in the second capture group.

Here's an example of it in use. I had to use a `slice` to cut off the last match in all cases, since allowing for blank fields with the `*` wildcard (things like `f1,,f3`) put a zero-width match at the end. This was easier to get rid of in-code rather than with some regex trickery. Finally, I've got `'extra_i'` as a default/placeholder value if there are some extra columns not accounted for by the headers. You should probably swap that part out to fit your own needs.

```js
/**
 * Takes a raw CSV string and converts it to a JavaScript object.
 * @param {string} text The raw CSV string.
 * @param {string[]} headers An optional array of headers to use. If none are
 * given, they are pulled from the first line of `text`.
 * @param {string} quoteChar A character to use as the encapsulating character.
 * @param {string} delimiter A character to use between columns.
 * @returns {object[]} An array of JavaScript objects containing headers as keys
 * and row entries as values.
 */
function csvToJson(text, headers, quoteChar = '"', delimiter = ',') {
  const regex = new RegExp(`\\s*(${quoteChar})?(.*?)\\1\\s*(?:${delimiter}|$)`, 'gs');

  const match = line => [...line.matchAll(regex)]
    .map(m => m[2])  // we only want the second capture group
    .slice(0, -1);   // cut off blank match at the end

  const lines = text.split('\n');
  const heads = headers ?? match(lines.shift());

  return lines.map(line => {
    return match(line).reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
      // Attempt to parse as a number; replace blank matches with `null`
      const val = cur.length <= 0 ? null : Number(cur) || cur;
      const key = heads[i] ?? `extra_${i}`;
      return { ...acc, [key]: val };
    }, {});
  });
}

const testString = `name,age,quote
John,,Hello World
Mary,23,""Alas, What Can I do?""
Joseph,45,"Waiting, waiting, waiting"
"Donaldson Jones"   , sixteen,    ""Hello, "my" friend!""`;

console.log(csvToJson(testString));
console.log(csvToJson(testString, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']));
console.log(csvToJson(testString, ['col_0']));
```

As a bonus, I've written this to allow for the passing of a list of strings to use as the headers instead, since I know first hand that not all CSV files have those.

---

**Note:** This regex approach does not work if your values have new-lines in them. This is because it relies on splitting the string at the newlines. I did look into using [this regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62900852/10549827) to split the lines only at newlines outside of quotes, which *almost* worked, but took upwards of 30 seconds on anything longer than a few lines.

If you want to get full functionality, your best bet would be to find an existing parsing library, or to write your own: one that counts occurrences of quotes to figure out if you're inside or outside a "cell" at the moment as you iterate through them.

Comment: This works! Thank you! Might you be able to show how you might handle the case where say, a field could be omitted? (say the sample string in the csv is "Joseph,,Happily Ever after" (without the surrounding quotes)

Comment: @Rolando Great question! After some time back in the lab I've updated my regex to handle blank spaces and also account for leading and trailing tabs/spaces. To account for the zero width matches that appeared at the end of each line, I used an in-place filter to pop off the last array element (the blank match). Cheers :-)

Comment: When tried I am getting commas inside all the headers like "call_status," . Could you please try to improve it

Comment: @GuruVishnuVardhanReddy After like... eight? months, your comment has been addressed. It was happening because I forgot to use the filter on the headers like I did with the other matches. Sorry it took so long 