# How to create a CSV File that will look Like This JSON File

Tags: json, csv, nft

I am basically wanting to update multiple scholars for an NFT game (axie infinity). It requires a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
        "name": "Scholar 1",
        "ronin": "ronin:<account_s1_address>",
        "splits": [
            {
                "persona": "Manager",
                "percentage": 44,
                "ronin": "ronin:<manager_address>"
            },
            {
                "persona": "Scholar",
                "percentage": 40,
                "ronin": "ronin:<scholar_1_address>"
            },
            {
                "persona": "Other Person",
                "percentage": 6,
                "ronin": "ronin:<other_person_address>"
            },
            {
                "persona": "Trainer",
                "percentage": 10,
                "ronin": "ronin:<trainer_address>"
            }
        ]
    }
```

But since there are multiple scholars/players, I wanted to know if there was anyway to format something on a CSV file that if I convert or import it using a JSON tool it will look like like the JSON above?

Your help is much appreciated.. Thank you!

PS:

The first lines:

```
"name": "Scholar 1",
            "ronin": "ronin:<account_s1_address>",
            "splits":
```

Would need to be repeated since again there are multiple scholars, i.e. Scholar 1, Scholar 2, Scholar 3...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to convert from CSV to JSON when commas and quotations may be in the fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59218548/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-from-csv-to-json-when-commas-and-quotations-may)

Answer (score 0):

CSV file structure is column-base, if Axie infinity require JSON file, you can create a CSV file by Excel or Google sheet and convert to JSON.

[there is a similar answer to convert CSV to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979002/convert-csv-data-into-json-format-using-javascript)

Comment: Hello.. Thanks for the answer.. I understand that a CSV file is column based.. But is there another way even if its not via CSV to create a JSON file that has multiple entries? I have created a JSON from CSV before when it was a bit simple to do.. But right now it seems from what I can see, I need to create a separate CSV file for each Scholar..? Is that right?

Comment: , you don't need separate CSV file. sperate scholars by ID, then  when creating json filter scholar data with ID. if you don't know programing language(s), csv is best format.

Answer (score 0):

starting from [this CSV](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aborruso/92a47116a883297eea1c18b7f257c132/raw/b9e41cb47f5f5827c4cb3f784bd04278cc26dbfa/out.csv) that has this structure

| name | ronin | id_persona | persona | percentage | split_ronin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Scholar 1 | ronin:<account_s1_address> | 1 | Manager | 44 | ronin:<manager_address> |
| Scholar 1 | ronin:<account_s1_address> | 2 | Scholar | 40 | ronin:<scholar_1_address> |
| Scholar 1 | ronin:<account_s1_address> | 3 | Other Person | 6 | ronin:<other_person_address> |
| Scholar 1 | ronin:<account_s1_address> | 4 | Trainer | 10 | ronin:<trainer_address> |

you can run this [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) command

```
mlr --c2j reshape -r "^(p|s)" -o k,v  then \
put '$k="splits".".".${id_persona}.".".$k' then \
cut -x -f id_persona then \
reshape -s k,v out.csv
```

to have

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Scholar 1",
    "ronin": "ronin:<account_s1_address>",
    "splits": [
      {
        "persona": "Manager",
        "percentage": 44,
        "split_ronin": "ronin:<manager_address>"
      },
      {
        "persona": "Scholar",
        "percentage": 40,
        "split_ronin": "ronin:<scholar_1_address>"
      },
      {
        "persona": "Other Person",
        "percentage": 6,
        "split_ronin": "ronin:<other_person_address>"
      },
      {
        "persona": "Trainer",
        "percentage": 10,
        "split_ronin": "ronin:<trainer_address>"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Some notes:

- `reshape -r "^(p|s)" -o k,v`, to transform the input from wide to long;
- `put '$k="splits".".".${id_persona}.".".$k'`, to create values that I will use as field names (`splits.1.persona,splits.1.percentage,splits.1.split_ronin,splits.2.persona,splits.2.percentage, ....`
- `cut -x -f id_persona`, to remove the field `id_persona`;
- `reshape -s k,v`, to transform all from long to wide.

The real goal is to build, starting from that input, this kind of CSV

```
+-----------+----------------------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| name      | ronin                      | splits.1.persona | splits.1.percentage | splits.1.split_ronin    | splits.2.persona | splits.2.percentage | splits.2.split_ronin      | splits.3.persona | splits.3.percentage | splits.3.split_ronin         | splits.4.persona | splits.4.percentage | splits.4.split_ronin    |
+-----------+----------------------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+
| Scholar 1 | ronin:<account_s1_address> | Manager          | 44                  | ronin:<manager_address> | Scholar          | 40                  | ronin:<scholar_1_address> | Other Person     | 6                   | ronin:<other_person_address> | Trainer          | 10                  | ronin:<trainer_address> |
+-----------+----------------------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------------+------------------+---------------------+------------------------------+------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+
```

and than use it to create the final JSON output