# Save CVS from the web to Apify Dataset

Tags: node.js, apify

I am trying to get some CVS data from google sheet and store it into an [Apify dataset](https://sdk.apify.com/docs/api/dataset).

```
const Apify = require('apify');
const request = require('request-promise');

Apify.main(async () => {

  var URL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-auXklWqHQ-jj6AXymMPa7FLtP1eYGJGF3rprxuWitk/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv";

  const html = await request(URL);
  console.log('My output:');
  console.log(html);

  await Apify.setValue('OUTPUT', html);

  const namedDataset = await Apify.openDataset();

  await namedDataset.pushData(html);
});
```

Here is error message:

```
2020-01-01T16:43:21.501Z My output:
2020-01-01T16:43:21.510Z "city","country"
2020-01-01T16:43:21.512Z "Berlin ","Germany"
2020-01-01T16:43:21.513Z "Los Angeles","United States"
2020-01-01T16:43:21.514Z "Melbourne","Australia"
2020-01-01T16:43:21.516Z "Sydney","Australia"
2020-01-01T16:43:21.517Z "London","United Kingdom"
2020-01-01T16:43:21.519Z "New York City","United States"
2020-01-01T16:43:21.614Z ERROR: The function passed to Apify.main() threw an exception: (error details: type=invalid-parameter)
2020-01-01T16:43:21.616Z   ApifyClientError: Parameter "data" of type Array | Object must be provided
2020-01-01T16:43:21.617Z     at exports.checkParamOrThrow (/usr/src/app/node_modules/apify-client/build/utils.js:222:15)
2020-01-01T16:43:21.619Z     at Dataset.pushData (/usr/src/app/node_modules/apify/build/dataset.js:222:34)
2020-01-01T16:43:21.620Z     at Apify.main (/usr/src/app/main.js:16:22)
2020-01-01T16:43:21.621Z     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more elegant solution would be using our [Google Sheets](https://apify.com/lukaskrivka/google-sheets) actor.

```
const Apify = require('apify');

Apify.main(async () => {
  const spreadsheetId = '1-auXklWqHQ-jj6AXymMPa7FLtP1eYGJGF3rprxuWitk';
  const sheetsActorInput = {
     mode: 'read',
     spreadsheetId,
  };
  const data = await Apify.call('lukaskrivka/google-sheets', sheetsActorInput);

  const namedDataset = await Apify.openDataset('my-dataset');
  await namedDataset.pushData(data);
});
```

The only disadvantage (also an advantage is some sense) is that you need to authorize in your first run but that is really simple.

Comment: does `spreadsheetId` in the `sheetsActorInput` object need to be `spreadsheetId: spreadsheetId`?

Comment: That is the same, I used the short notation.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use this somewhat hacky approach. I am sure their is a more modern elgagent approach:

```
const Apify = require('apify');
const request = require('request-promise');

function csvJSON(csv) { //https://stackoverflow.com/a/27979069/2330272
  var lines = csv.split("\n");
  var result = [];
  // NOTE: If your columns contain commas in their values, you'll need
  // to deal with those before doing the next step 
  // (you might convert them to &&& or something, then covert them back later)
  // jsfiddle showing the issue https://jsfiddle.net/
  var headers = lines[0].split(",");
  for (var i = 1; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var obj = {};
    var currentline = lines[i].split(",");
    for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
    }
    result.push(obj);
  }
  return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
}

Apify.main(async () => {
  var URL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-auXklWqHQ-jj6AXymMPa7FLtP1eYGJGF3rprxuWitk/gviz/tq?tqx=out:csv"; //test
  const html = await request(URL);
  const urls = csvJSON(html.replace(/\"/g, "")); // remove quotes from csv data
  console.log('My output:');
  const namedDataset = await Apify.openDataset();
  await namedDataset.pushData(JSON.parse(urls));
});
```

Comment: Yes, you cannot push raw CSV string, you have to push object or array of objects.