# How to convert CSV to an array of JS objetcs

Tags: javascript, csv

I am getting a below structure after converting a CSV file to a JS object

```
"category,name,includeInAuto,srNumber,testType
"Test1","Name1","true",1,"type1"
"Test2","Name2","true",1,"type2"
"Test3","Name3","true",1,"type3"
"Test4","Name4","true",1,"type4"
"Test5","Name5","true",1,"type5"
"Test6","Name6","true",1,"type6"
"Test7","Name7","true",1,"type7"
```

And I am trying to convert it like below

```
[{"category": "Test1", "name": "Name1", "includeInAuto": "true", "srNumber": 1 "testType": "type1"},
 {"category": "Test2", "name": "Name2", "includeInAuto": "true", "srNumber": 2 "testType": "type2"},
 {"category": "Test3", "name": "Name3", "includeInAuto": "true", "srNumber": 3 "testType": "type3"},
 {"category": "Test4", "name": "Name4", "includeInAuto": "true", "srNumber": 4 "testType": "type4"},
 {"category": "Test5", "name": "Name5", "includeInAuto": "true", "srNumber": 5 "testType": "type5"},
 {"category": "Test6", "name": "Name6", "includeInAuto": "true", "srNumber": 6 "testType": "type6"},
 {"category": "Test7", "name": "Name7", "includeInAuto": "true", "srNumber": 7 "testType": "type7"}]
```

I have tried using map like `Object.entries(obj);` or `Object.keys(obj);`  or converting it an array first `Array.from(obj)` but not getting an expected result.

above all approaches separates each word to a single character like category to "c","a","t","e","g","o","r","y"

Can someone please help me to achieve the same?

**UPDATE**

if I edit the csv file in excel and then try to parse it then I get a below structure where instead of surrounding all the values with double quotes whole data is surrounded in double quotes as below

```
"category,name,includeInAuto,srNumber,testType 
Test1,Name1,true,1,type1 
Test2,Name2,true,2,type2
Test3,Name3,true,3,type3
Test4,Name4,true,4,type4
Test5,Name5,true,5,type5
Test6,Name6,true,6,type6
Test7,Name7,true,7,type7"
```

if instead of above any of the value has any special character in it lets assume if I change name7 to name,7 then FileReader return below structure

```
"category,name,includeInAuto,srNumber,testType 
    Test1,Name1,true,1,type1 
    Test2,Name2,true,2,type2
    Test3,Name3,true,3,type3
    Test4,Name4,true,4,type4
    Test5,Name5,true,5,type5
    Test6,Name6,true,6,type6
    Test7,\"Name,7\",true,6,type6"
```

in above whole csv string is in double quotes but the name name, 7 is also in double quotes with some extra slashes now instead of 4 comma separated values we have 5 comma separated values.

Comment: Thank you Teemu, yes this is a CSV, I have updated my question.

Comment: You can use this cool library `csv-parse` if that is okay

Comment: Thank you RaR for your response, by any chance would you please suggest a manual approach other than JS library.

Comment: Your CSV data is a string? How you assigned that into a variable?

Comment: Parsing CSV data is a non-trivial exercise so using an existing, well tested library would certainly be my preference over writing something bespoke.

Comment: use the technique provided in this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979002/convert-csv-data-into-json-format-using-javascript

Comment: You should leave the quotes. You need them in case there are commas in the data. [I used them to parse the line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61473879/295783)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my try on your SPECIFIC example WITH qoutes

```js
const parseCsv = csv => {
  let lines = csv.split("\n");
  const header = lines.shift().split(",")
  return  lines.map(line => {
    const bits = JSON.parse("[" + line + "]")
    let obj = {};
    header.forEach((h, i) => obj[h] = bits[i]); // or use reduce here
    // optional:
    obj["includeInAuto"] = obj["includeInAuto"] === "true";
    return obj;
  });
};

const csv = `category,name,includeInAuto,srNumber,testType
"Test1","Name1","true",1,"type1"
"Test2","Name2","true",1,"type2"
"Test3","Name3","true",1,"type3"
"Test4","Name4","true",1,"type4"
"Test5","Name5","true",1,"type5"
"Test6","Name6","true",1,"type6"
"Test7","Name7","true",1,"type7"`

console.log(parseCsv(csv));
```

Without quotes:

```js
const parseCsv = csv => {
  let lines = csv.split(/\r?\n/);
  const header = lines.shift().split(",")
  return  lines.map(line => {
    const bits = line.split(",")
    let obj = {};
    header.forEach((h, i) => obj[h] = bits[i]); // or use reduce here
    // optional:
    obj["includeInAuto"] = obj["includeInAuto"] === "true";
    return obj;
  });
};

const csv = `category,name,includeInAuto,srNumber,testType
Test1,Name1,true,1,type1
Test2,Name2,true,1,type2
Test3,Name3,true,1,type3
Test4,Name4,true,1,type4
Test5,Name5,true,1,type5
Test6,Name6,true,1,type6
Test7,Name7,true,1,type7`


console.log(parseCsv(csv));
```

With escaped quotes

```js
const parseCsv = csv => {
  let lines = csv.slice(1,csv.length-1).split(/\r?\n/);
  console.log(lines)
  const header = lines.shift().split(",")
  return  lines.map(line => {
    const bits = line.trim().split(/,(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/);
    let obj = {};
    header.forEach((h, i) => obj[h] = bits[i].replace(/\"/g,"")); // or use reduce here
    // optional:
    obj["includeInAuto"] = obj["includeInAuto"] === "true";
    return obj;
  });
};

const csv = `"category,name,includeInAuto,srNumber,testType 
    Test1,Name1,true,1,type1 
    Test2,Name2,true,2,type2
    Test3,Name3,true,3,type3
    Test4,Name4,true,4,type4
    Test5,Name5,true,5,type5
    Test6,Name6,true,6,type6
    Test7,\"Name,7\",true,6,type6"`


console.log(parseCsv(csv));
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212706/discussion-on-answer-by-mplungjan-how-to-convert-csv-to-an-array-of-js-objetcs).

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using a dedicated CSV parser, like [PapaParse](https://www.papaparse.com/), this is exactly what they are designed to do.

Parsing CSV data can get really tricky once you get into quoting etc.

```js
let csv  = `category,name,includeInAuto,srNumber,testType
"Test1","Name1","true",1,"type1"
"Test2","Name2","true",1,"type2"
"Test3","Name3","true",1,"type3"
"Test4","Name4","true",1,"type4"
"Test5","Name5","true",1,"type5"
"Test6","Name6","true",1,"type6"
"Test7","Name7","true",1,"type7"`;

let result = Papa.parse(csv, { header: true, dynamicTyping: true });
console.log("Result:", result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.1.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Terry for your answer but I have to use this js code in Salesforce but I cannot use 3rd party libraries in script tag instead I have to download the zip file of thrid party JS and give the reference of that zip file in the code, but if I download the zip file from papaparse's website then size of zip file is around 13 MB but I cannot use zip file of more than 5 mb, would you please suggest on this?

Comment: The PapaParse library should be a lot smaller than that, I think it's more like 19kb - https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.1.0/papaparse.min.js. You should be able to download this to include!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. Here's a snippet that uses a [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for the csv-lines. If the csv gets more complex (e.g. nested `"` etc), you may want to write a parser (it's fun!) or use [some external library](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=csv) to parse csv-files.

```js
const csv = `category,name,includeInAuto,srNumber,testType
"Test1","Name1","true",1,"type1"
"Test2","Name2","true",1,"type2"
"Test3","Name3","true",1,"type3"
"Test4","Name4","true",1,"type4"
"Test5","Name5","true",1,"type5"
"Test6","Name6","true",1,"type6"
"Test7","Name7","true",1,"type7"`.split("\n");

// get headers  
const headers = csv[0].split(",");

// helper to create a row from values 
// (using the just created headers)
const createRow = values => headers.reduce( (acc, header, i) => 
  ({...acc, [header]: values[i]}), {});

// reduce csv-lines to Array of Objects
const csv2Obj = csv
  .slice(1) // no need for headers ofcourse
  .reduce( (acc, row) => ([...acc, createRow(row.replace(/"/g, "").split(","))]), []);

console.log(csv2Obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: I gotta ask, why a regex for `\n`?

Comment: I suppose it's ... habit ;)

Comment: thank you for your response, the above code works fine if I have the values surrounded in quotes, otherwise I get an error "exception SyntaxError: Unexpected token T in JSON at position 1", I have updated my question as well.

Comment: @gs650x `csv2Obj` should be generated *with or without quotes* around the csv values. The error you get is not related to the snippet code, but to something you are doing with JSON (JSON is not a part of the given snippet).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to solve this.

```js
let csv = `category,name,includeInAuto,srNumber,testType
"Test1","Name1","true",1,"type1"
"Test2","Name2","true",1,"type2"
"Test3","Name3","true",1,"type3"
"Test4","Name4","true",1,"type4"
"Test5","Name5","true",1,"type5"
"Test6","Name6","true",1,"type6"
"Test7","Name7","true",1,"type7"`;


let data = csv.split("\n");
let title = data.shift().split(",");

let array = data.reduce((arr, row) => {
  row = row.replace(/"/g, "");
  let innerObj = row.split(",").reduce((obj, item, index) => {
    obj[title[index]] = item;
    return obj;
  }, {});
  arr.push(innerObj);
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for the suggestion. I've fixed that.

Comment: Your digit is still a string and your code will fail if there are commas in the content: `"Test1","Surname1, FirstName1","true",1,"type1"` - this is not a good idea: `row = row.replace(/"/g, "");` see my version for a better way