# Angular:Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to import an excel with this code but I get this error

[Angular Ag Grid Excel Import](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-excel-import?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
```

This File import
Can this type of file be imported?

Book.csv

```
1,chocolate,brown,10
2,gum,red,11
3,juice,yellow,5
```

I read the app.component.ts file it says that I can import 4 columns.

app.component.ts

```
    var columns = {
        'A': '',
        'B': 'Make',
        'C': 'Model',
        'D': 'Price'
    };
```

Comment: What are the expected file types? If its only CSV, you do not need any other library. You can just parse the file as text like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61473549/how-to-convert-csv-to-an-array-of-js-objetcs)

Comment: [ask] -> Add a [mcve] _in the question itself_

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs in this section of the App component code

```
 populateGrid(file: any) {
    // our data is in the first sheet
    var firstSheetName = file.SheetNames[0];
```

The `SheetNames` field is missing in the `file` argument (=undefined).
Check the type of the accepted object

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer.

Comment: I would argue it justifies an answer since it seems to find the problem and work toward an answer. More detail would definitely make it better