# Reactjs converting a csv file in local to json

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to convert a .csv file into a JSON object in Reactjs. For this, I add the file I need to convert into the project structure under a folder called Data. I then found this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-csv-to-json and tried the following piece of code to convert file

```
import { getJsonFromCsv } from "convert-csv-to-json";
...
let json = getJsonFromCsv('./Data/finaldata.csv');
for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
console.log(json[i]);
}
```

But trying this is throwing an

> "TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function"

So I would like to know if something is wrong with my code or Can someone suggest another method to convert CSV file to JSON

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert CSV data into JSON format using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979002/convert-csv-data-into-json-format-using-javascript)

Comment: I tried one of the answers in that using papa-parse but it seems react-papa-parse only works if I upload a file and then read it. But I don't want to upload I just want to read from a file that is already in project structure

Comment: Many solutions work if we upload the file and then parse it. but I am looking for one where we need not upload file we read it from local storage and parse it

Answer (score 3):

@kartik
try it

```js
//var csv is the CSV file with headers
function csvJSON(csv){

  var lines=csv.split("\n");

  var result = [];

  var headers=lines[0].split(",");

  for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){

   var obj = {};
   var currentline=lines[i].split(",");

   for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
    obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
   }

   result.push(obj);

  }
  
  //return result; //JavaScript object
  return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
}
```

Comment: i understood the function but how to pass my required file as param to that function. Could you answer that by assuming the required file is in local storage

Answer (score 2):

`fs` is the Node.js file system module, it can not use in browsers environment. Consider use browser compatible library like [PapaParse](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse).