# Import csv data from react

Tags: json, reactjs, csv

I want to make a bulk insert from a csv with columns names different to the ones in my database. I am developing a **React** web and would like to convert it to **json** with the correct columns names.

Here is an example

```
Csv:
Prod,price,stock
Shirt,200,12
```

Json:

```
{User_prod:'Shirt',User_price:'200',user_stock:'12'}
```

Thanks!

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979002/convert-csv-data-into-json-format-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the react csv libraries for loading and manipulating the csv header.

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv-reader
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-csv