# How can I generate a list of thumbnails in a local html file from a list of product codes from a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, database, automation

I'm looking for an easier way to look at product images.
Currently I individually search for them from a spreadsheet list. This feels tedious so I'm wondering if there is a way to automatically generate this list as main product images in a html file just. I'd just need to reference the website and the list of codes to crawl then.

Thanks for your help

J :)

I don't have any specific js hoping you have some cool idea
[here is a screenshot of the spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mk5E.png)

Comment: How are you getting the products from that website? Is there an API which returns a JSON response? What have you tried, code-wise? If there's no remote API, you mentioned going through a spreadsheet and manually searching for what you need. What about saving that spreadsheet as a CSV file and [parsing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27979002/convert-csv-data-into-json-format-using-javascript)?

Comment: Sounds complex. I was thinking it could just be done with HTML and javascript. Don't have any idea or experience with JSON or API

Comment: yes I want to read the products from the website. I have a list of the product codes

Comment: Can you post the structure of your spreadsheet (columns), and one row, as an example? You can edit your question, and just post it as an image.

Comment: Thanks posted above :)

Comment: If it's possible, can you also post the structure of the local HTML file? You don't have to post the entire contents, just the part where the products are mentioned. This is needed so that I (or any other SO user) can see how to get the product information from your HTML and to compare it with what you have in your spreadsheet.

Comment: I've made something for you to test in the meantime. Let me know if it works for you, and I'll post it as a complete answer, with additional explanations. The fiddle can be [found here](https://jsfiddle.net/xofqsnmL/1/). It assumes a certain structure for your local HTML file. The fiddle expects a CSV file (you can find the contents of it [here](https://pastebin.com/K9zj2xxx) - just copy / paste it into Notepad, and save it as a CSV).

Comment: Wow Thanks this looks amazing! 

I copied it to my desktop, but I've no idea how to generate the products or what to put in the body of the HTML file as I want the product images to auto generate? For example how do I pull specific products from this website? https://www.jdwilliams.co.uk/

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not open that website - it seems that my country is blocked for some reason.